# Can anyone tell what happens when we use exact in routes file. And use history,push to that route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, history.js

```
export const updateData =
  (data, history) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const promise = putRequest(`${url}`, data, dispatch, getState)
      .then(() => {
        history.push("/p/someroute/")
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error, dispatch);
      });
    return promise;
  };
```

The above code pushes the route to "/" homepage.
and if i see console.log(history) there, i can see action as "REPLACE" instead of "PUSH".

Why this can happen?

```
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path="/p/someroute/"
        component={SomeComponent}
        role={USER_ROLES.get("ADMIN")}
      />
```

This is my route code.

I tried placing debugger; above history.push, GOT ACTION AS PUSH.
As soon as that line of code executes, ACTION converts to REPLACE, and routes to "/" home directory route.

Comment: I suspect this `PrivateRoute` component is redirecting to `"/"` after an auth check? Perhaps the `role` doesn't match. ‍♂️ Can you [edit] the post to include all relevant code you are working with and asking about? See [mcve].

Comment: Doesnt work . Even i change it to 
```
<Route exact path="/someroute" compoent={SomeComponent} />
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Is this a response to a now-deleted comment?

Answer (score 0):

I tried history.goBack()
And it worked for me as I wanted to go back one page.